# How to install Text_Highlighter PEAR package?

Tags: php, pear

I've tried a lot of possible solutions but no one helped:

```
pear install Text_Highlighter
Failed to download pear/Text_Highlighter within preferred state "stable", latest release is version 0.7.2, stability "beta", use "channel://pear.php.net/Text_Highlighter-0.7.2" to install


pear -d preferred_state=beta install -f channel://pear.php.net/Text_Highlighter-0.7.2
downloading Text_Highlighter-0.7.2.tgz ...
Starting to download Text_Highlighter-0.7.2.tgz (139,104 bytes)
..............................done: 139,104 bytes
ERROR: No releases in package.xml matched the existing operating system, extensions installed, or architecture, cannot install
```

Etc. Whereas 0.7.1 installs perfectly using the latest command

Any ideas?

**UPD**:

This is what `php pyrus.phar install pear/Text_Highlighter-0.7.2` gives to me:

```
Downloading pear.php.net/Text_Highlighter

Connected...
Mime-type: application/octet-stream

Downloading pear.php.net/PEAR=======================================================================>] 99% (134/135 kb)
Connected...
Mime-type: application/octet-stream

Downloading pear.php.net/Archive_Tar================================================================>] 99% (288/289 kb)
Connected...
Mime-type: application/octet-stream

Downloading pear.php.net/Structures_Graph=====================================================>      ] 93% (16/17 kb)
Connected...
Mime-type: application/octet-stream

Downloading pear.php.net/XML_Util================================================================>   ] 96% (28/29 kb)
Connected...
Mime-type: application/octet-stream

Downloading pear.php.net/XML_Parser===========================================================>      ] 93% (16/17 kb)
Connected...
Mime-type: application/octet-stream

Downloading pear.php.net/Console_Getopt======================================================>       ] 92% (14/15 kb)
Connected...
Mime-type: application/octet-stream

PHP Warning:  rmdir(/usr/.old-bin/X11): Not a directory in phar:///root/pyrus.phar/PEAR2_Pyrus-2.0.0a3/php/PEAR2/Pyrus/Filesystem.php on line 66
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /root/pyrus.phar:0
PHP   2. PEAR2\Pyrus\ScriptFrontend\Commands->run() /root/pyrus.phar:52
PHP   3. PEAR2\Pyrus\ScriptFrontend\Commands->install() phar:///root/pyrus.phar/PEAR2_Pyrus-2.0.0a3/php/PEAR2/Pyrus/ScriptFrontend/Commands.php:284
PHP   4. PEAR2\Pyrus\Installer::commit() phar:///root/pyrus.phar/PEAR2_Pyrus-2.0.0a3/php/PEAR2/Pyrus/ScriptFrontend/Commands.php:491
PHP   5. PEAR2\Pyrus\AtomicFileTransaction::removeBackups() phar:///root/pyrus.phar/PEAR2_Pyrus-2.0.0a3/php/PEAR2/Pyrus/Installer.php:349
PHP   6. PEAR2\Pyrus\AtomicFileTransaction\Manager->finish() phar:///root/pyrus.phar/PEAR2_Pyrus-2.0.0a3/php/PEAR2/Pyrus/AtomicFileTransaction.php:96
PHP   7. PEAR2\Pyrus\AtomicFileTransaction\Transaction\TwoStage->finish() phar:///root/pyrus.phar/PEAR2_Pyrus-2.0.0a3/php/PEAR2/Pyrus/AtomicFileTransaction/Manager.php:196
PHP   8. PEAR2\Pyrus\Filesystem::rmrf() phar:///root/pyrus.phar/PEAR2_Pyrus-2.0.0a3/php/PEAR2/Pyrus/AtomicFileTransaction/Transaction/TwoStage.php:107
PHP   9. rmdir() phar:///root/pyrus.phar/PEAR2_Pyrus-2.0.0a3/php/PEAR2/Pyrus/Filesystem.php:66
PEAR2\Pyrus\AtomicFileTransaction\MultiException: Warning: no all backup directories have been removed
 PEAR2\Pyrus\IOException: Unable to fully remove /usr/.old-bin
```

Comment: did you try this metod> php pyrus.phar install pear/Text_Highlighter-0.7.2

Comment: @B14D3: just did it, with even worse results :-S

Comment: what is this operating system ?? linux or windows??

Comment: do you have all dependencies installed for Text_Highlighter-0.7.2

Comment: @B14D3: I don't know about dependencies (and even more - there is no dependencies described in `package.xml`). `--alldeps` changes nothing. Isn't dependencies tracking is what package managers were invited for? If I tracked dependencies by myself I wouldn't need `pear` at all. It is `Ubuntu 10.04.3 LTS`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug in a package itself. Filled and fixed at http://pear.php.net/bugs/bug.php?id=19139

Answer (score 2):

Right now the Text_Highlighter package has a dependency on PEAR, which means it will pull in a bunch of other packages. To install the package into a self-contained repository you can use:

```
mkdir Text_Highlighter
cd Text_Highlighter
php pyrus.phar `pwd` set bin_dir `pwd`/bin
php pyrus.phar `pwd` install pear/Text_Highlighter-0.7.2
```

Which will install Text_Highlighter-0.7.2 and all dependencies in the Text_Highlighter directory.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Anyway it was a bug in the package description: http://pear.php.net/bugs/bug.php?id=19139